# DB2 on cloud not supporting pl/sql

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to run PL/SQL code like

```
DECLARE
  sum INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    sum := sum + 1;
    IF sum > 10 THEN
       EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END
```

But the code above and, in fact, any PL/SQL code is not getting executed and throws errors.

Comment: And the error messages?

Comment: How do you run the statement? Is it in the browser UI or in another Db2 client connected to that database? What service plan do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can [execute PL/SQL statements against Db2 on Cloud](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053607.html) when using the proper client and when the Oracle compatibility mode is active. Not every database client supports executing the statements because of their structure, handling of terminators and the way PL/SQL and SQL/PL statements and procedures (in general) are called.